# Toggler and Dropdown not workin

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, partials, express-handlebars

I'm learning to use Bootstrap and neither the Toggler nor the Dropdown expand, I honestly don't know if I'm doing something wrong

I'm learning to use Bootstrap and neither the Toggler nor the Dropdown expand, I honestly don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

Here is the navbar code (It's a partial, I'm using Handlebars)

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03"
      aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Titleee</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Withepaper</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded="false">
            Community
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Discord</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Telegram</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to import bootstrap.js file also to make togglers and dropdowns, work,

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Or could just import the single bundle as well: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`